# Lucene Apache Only Finds 10 Files

Tags: java, lucene

I created 500 copies of a file and made Lucene Apache index them all. I named them like "0.txt", "1.txt", "2.txt"..."499.txt". When I search for a specific word it returns files from 0 to 9 while it was supposed to return 0 to 499.

This is my indexer:

```
public class Indexer {

private IndexWriter writer;

public Indexer(String indexDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
    new File(indexDirectoryPath).mkdirs();
    Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
    writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config);
}

public void close() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
    writer.close();
}

private Document getDocument(File file) throws IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    Field contentField = new Field(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, new FileReader(file));
    Field fileNameField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME, file.getName(), Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    Field filePathField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH, file.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    document.add(contentField);
    document.add(fileNameField);
    document.add(filePathField);
    return document;
}

public void indexFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Document document = getDocument(file);
    writer.addDocument(document);
}}
```

This is my Searcher:

```
public class Searcher {
IndexSearcher indexSearcher;
QueryParser queryParser;
Query query;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Searcher(String indexDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
    Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory
            .open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);
    queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,
            LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, new StandardAnalyzer(
                    Version.LUCENE_36));
}

public TopDocs search(String searchQuery) throws IOException,
        ParseException {
    query = queryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(searchQuery));
    return indexSearcher.search(query, LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);
}

public Document getDocument(ScoreDoc scoreDoc)
        throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
    return indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    indexSearcher.close();
}}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
Indexer indexer = new Indexer(DIR_INDEX);
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                indexer.indexFile(new File("files/" + i + ".txt"));
            }
            indexer.close();
            Searcher searcher = new Searcher(DIR_INDEX);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.search("Saude");
            for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
                org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
                System.out.println(doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));
            }
            searcher.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
indexSearcher.search(query, LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);
```

the second parameter is the maximum number of returned hits; check that value, it is probably 10.

Comment: That's it. I apologize for this stupid mistake and sadly I can't upvote you.